# Превращение ссылки в кнопку

Tags: html, jquery

Возможно ли при помощи JQuery заставить `<a>` выполнять действие `<input type="submit">`?
Если "да", то как и какие методы использовать?

Comment: у тебя `<input type="submit">` расположен в форме?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский да

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Банально ставим обработчик `click` на ссылку. При клике вызываем `submit` у формы.

```js
$(document).on('click', '#submit-form', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('form').submit();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<form action="/test/yo" method="post">
  <input type="text" value="test">  
</form>

<a href="#" id="submit-form">click</a>
```

При таком подходе даже не обязательно, чтобы `#submit-form` был ссылкой. Можно клик установить вообще на любой элемент. Главное тут вызвать сабмит формы  `$('form').submit();`

Answer (score 2):

Можно просто делать `submit` формы при клике на ссылку:

```js
$("#linkSubmit").on("click", function() {
  $("#form").submit();
  return false;
});
```

```html
<form id="form" action="save">
  <input name="key" value="value" />
</form>
<a id="linkSubmit" href="">Link submit</a>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

Если обязательно нужно нажать именно на `<input type="submit">`, то тогда можно сделать именно это:

```js
$("#linkSubmit").on("click", function() {
  $("#inputSubmit").click();
  return false;
});
```

```html
<form id="form" action="save">
  <input name="key" value="value" />
  <input id="inputSubmit" type="submit" />
</form>
<a id="linkSubmit" href="">Link submit</a>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```